# How to center placeholder/input text in an input field, but keep the cursor left aligned

Tags: html, css

I want to center both the placeholder and the typed input in an input field, but when there is no input I want the cursor to remain left-aligned. For example, if I use:

```css
input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}

::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="hello">
```

this will successfully align my placeholder and any input I type into the center, but makes the cursor flash in the center of the placeholder instead of to the left

I would want to cursor to be before the h in "hello" which is the placeholder in the input, but when I type any input the functionality should remain the same, i.e. the input should be centered. The cursor should only be left aligned when there is no input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this considering [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown). No need for JS

```css
input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}

::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

input:placeholder-shown {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="hello">
```

Comment: It should be noted, that this method doesn‘t work in Internet Explorer or EDGE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, I'm toggling the text-align property based on whether or not your input contains a value. I know it kind of snaps into the center of the input box and is not smooth, but I don't know if you can change anything about that.

```js
let inp = document.getElementById("inp");

inp.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (!inp.value) {
  inp.style.textAlign = "left";
 } else {
   inp.style.textAlign = "center";
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 60px;
}

input::placeholder {
  text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" type = "text" placeholder = "hello">
```