# Is it possible to make the placeholder attribute of an input element remain the same even after entering a value

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder

In the website I am making, I am styling the placeholder attribute of the input element to translate upwards. I was wondering if it possible to keep the placeholder attribute the same even after entering text in the element.

This is my CSS

```
.inputbox {
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-style: none none double none;
    border-color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    transition: border-color 0.3s;
}

.inputbox:focus {
    border-color: #111;
}

.inputbox::placeholder {
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.inputbox:focus::placeholder {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    color: #111;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'same', shouldn't the placeholder value disappear after a value is entered? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565117/8620333

Comment: Yes, it does. I was wondering if it was possible to keep the placeholder from disappearing after entering some input into the element.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the text entered incomprehensible, since it would overlap with the placeholder?

Comment: I used the css to move it upwards so it wouldn't overlap

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901797/is-it-possible-to-transition-placeholder-text-from-beginning-to-end) question's answer by @TemaniAfif is what you are looking for.

Comment: I just checked that answer. What I am looking for is to keep the placeholder text even after inputting some text into the element.

Comment: So is there a way to keep the placeholder attribute from disappearing after input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to keep the placeholder attribute after inputting some text. The best way I could work through it was to use the `<label>` tag.